# Merge PostgreSQL queries with different columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 4 distinct select statements, each of which returns a single column.  Each select returns a different column name though.  For example, the first select is 'TotalPeople' and the second select is 'Complete'.

Instead of returning two result sets, each with a single row, I'd rather return one result set, where I have as many columns as I have select statements.

Is that possible?

So lets say these are my two queries:

```sql
SELECT count(people) FROM someTable WHERE ...
SELECT count(complete) FROM someOtherTable WHERE ...
```

I would get back two result sets, like:

```
| people |  
|--------|  
| 123    |  

| complete |  
|----------|  
| 15       |
```

Instead, I'd like to get back

```
| people | complete |  
|--------|----------|  
| 123    | 15       |
```

Comment: sample data, the current query and the expected results would help.

Comment: I updated the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably better ways to do what you want.  But, you can combine the queries either in the `select` or the `from`.  For instance:

```
select q1.TotalPeople, q2.Complete
from (<q1>) q1 cross join
     (<q2>) q2;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select count(table_people.id) AS PEOPLE, 
(select count(table_number.id) 
from table_number) AS NUMBER
from table_people;
```

Here you can use sub queries to group both queries together.
Hope it helps.